# SQL Server Execution Plan Recommends Creating a NONClustered Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the following query I've created, and it takes about 38 secs to run.

```
SELECT 
    PartNo, 
    SerialNo, 
    HeciCode, 
    ScanDate, 
    OrderType, 
    PoNo,  
    po.IssueDate, 
    SoNo 
FROM ScanHistory sh WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trkRWPOHeader po WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON sh.PoNo = po.PONum 
WHERE len(PoNo) > 2 
    AND ScanDate > '1/1/2009' 
    AND PartNo = 'RDH102472' 
    AND sh.SerialNo NOT IN (SELECT SerialNo 
                            FROM ScanHistory WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE PONo = '' 
                                OR (OrderType = 'SO' AND SoNo = '000001') 
                            ) 
    AND sh.SerialNo NOT IN (SELECT i.SerialNo       
                            FROM skp_SkidItem i with (nolock) 
                            INNER JOIN skp_Skid sk with (nolock) 
                                ON i.SkidNo = sk.SkidNo 
                            WHERE sk.SkidStatus = 'Shipped' 
                                or i.ItemStatus = 'Shipped'
                            ) 
ORDER BY PoNo
```

Under the Recent Expensive Queries section in the Sql Server Activity monitor it shows me the execution plan with the following recommendation (or issue):

```
Missing Index (Impact 51.4221): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<name of missing index, sysname,>] ON dbo.ScanHistory (PartNo, ScanDate)
```

My question is:

How to create this Nonclustered Index based on the query I have?

I've written several complex queries in Sql Server but really haven't delved into Nonclustered indexes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Based on that query, I would think a better index would be on PartNo, ScanDate, and SerialNo. Oh and whatever logic you have with the len(PoNo) > 2 should be changed. I'm assuming it is a validation check to ensure the PO is good; make a different column for PoStatus or something. LEN(PoNo) can't use an index.

Comment: This part of the recommendation text didn't give you a hint?   `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<name of missing index, sysname,>] ON dbo.ScanHistory (PartNo, ScanDate)`

Answer (score 1):

1. The recommended indexes provided by SSMS are not always the best.
2. Don't go making indexes without approval from your DBA if this is at work or if this is a personal project, research indexes before deploying them. They are not free, they impact your environment, and they need to be maintained.
3. To create that specific suggested query, turn on Include Actual Execution Plan in SSMS, run that query, change over to the Execution plan tab, the suggested missing index should be in green text, right click it, script it to a new window, give it a unique name, and execute the query.

If the message you provided is the index you want to make, remove the first part and rename it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_your_unique_name_here] 
    ON dbo.ScanHistory (PartNo, ScanDate)
```

Comment: Upvoted for the quote "The recommended indexes provided by SSMS are not always the best."  even when they are useful, you have to know what you are doing before you implement them.